# adding zeros in front of a string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How to add zeros in front of a string in Objective-C so that the length of the new string will be equal to a specific value? For example, if the specific length is 6,

```
  1 --> 000001
 12 --> 000012
123 --> 000123
...
```

Besides, I don't want to use loops. More elegant, more pleasure.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%06ld", yourNumber];`

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually think an easier solution than this:

```
NSInteger yourNumber = 12; // or your random number...
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%06ld", yourNumber]);
```

That presents the output on the console:

```
000012
```